# send images by sockets over the network

Tags: c#, sockets

So, I finally managed to make a conection but now im trying to pass images over the server.

The code looks like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //StartConnectionVideo();
    Client = new TcpClient();
     Client.Connect("10.0.0.3", 456);
     //Connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3700
     readingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartReading));
     //Start a new thread to receive images

     readingThread.Start();
 }

private void StartReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("D");
            NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream();


                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
                MessageBox.Show("D");
                    //Deserialize the image from the NetworkStream

                    MessageBox.Show(img.Width.ToString());
                    pictureBox1.Image = img; //Show the image in the picturebox

              }

        }
    }
```

the first message box work(directlry after the loop) but on the second its stuck.
it's just hangs on this line

```
        Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

the server side is this..

```
      Image img=Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\איתמר\Desktop\air\amumu_0.jpg");
        VideoServer a = new VideoServer(img ,this);
        a.StartListening();
        //a.padre.pictureBox1.Image = img;
        a.SendImage(img);
```

videoserver is a class i wrote... i'll write here the main important code pieces

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
        // Create the TCP listener object using the IP of the server and the specified port
        tlsClient = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Any, 456);

        // Start the TCP listener and listen for connections
        tlsClient.Start();

        // The while loop will check for true in this before checking for connections
        ServRunning = true;

        thrListener = new Thread(KeepListening);
        thrListener.Start();

    }  

   public void SendImage(Image img)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ClientList.Count; i++)
        {
            TcpClient tempClient = (TcpClient)ClientList[i];
            if (tempClient.Connected) //If the client is connected
            {

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();


                formatter.Serialize(tempClient.GetStream(), img);
                //Serialize the image to the tempClient NetworkStream
            }
            else
            {
                ClientList.Remove(tempClient);
                i--;
            }

        }
```

i think i've showed the main code... the rest isnt so important because im prettry sure the problem is in this code...

i appriciate any help of you guys im breaking my head over a week :D

Comment: Probably the `Image.FromStream()` method reads until end of stream. You'll have to use a new socket, or a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are serializing the image using `BinaryFormatter` but deserializing it using `Image.FromStream`. These are two incompatible formats. You must use the same format both times.

As far as I'm aware `Image.FromStream` is not documented to cope with infinite streams. In fact I'm quite sure it doesn't because by principle it cannot avoid reading two much (except if it were reading byte-wise which is a performance nightmare). Therefore, you can't use `Image.FromStream` directly.

I'd do this by first converting the image to a `byte[]` or a `MemoryStream`. Then I would first write the length of the image data and then the data. A length prefix is a common way of serializing things.

Or, use a higher-level abstraction such as protobuf.